# How to capture specific character arrangements or a word form a line using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to read following sample line and grab a specific word from that line.

sample line

```
#apple (orange3ball/345-35:;bat9cap/253-43) school=(book,pen,bottle)
```

Let say I want to grab word 'orange3ball' (in between ('(' and '/') and 'bat9cap' and 'bottle' . what is the best way to do it.

I tried with split() function but I couldn't do it properly.

If it is too difficult to do can I search a specif arrangements of characters in a line.

As an example can I find the 'bat9cap' character arrangement from the above line.

Comment: What do you mean by "grab"? Are you looking for the location of these words within your string? Or to identify if they are present?

Comment: to identify the word

Comment: To identify if `orange3ball` is in the string `line`, use `'orange3ball' in line` which returns `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for the interactive shell! Make a variable containing the line in question and experiment away. Here I did it for you to show you one slightly convoluted way to "grab" the word between ( and /.

```
>>> line = "#apple (orange3ball/345-35:;bat9cap/253-43) school=(book,pen,bottle)"
>>> line.split()
['#apple', '(orange3ball/345-35:;bat9cap/253-43)', 'school=(book,pen,bottle)']
>>> line.split()[1]
'(orange3ball/345-35:;bat9cap/253-43)'
>>> line.split()[1].split("/")
['(orange3ball', '345-35:;bat9cap', '253-43)']
>>> line.split()[1].split("/")[0]
'(orange3ball'
>>> line.split()[1].split("/")[0].strip("(")
'orange3ball'
```

Notice that I just pressed uparrow to get the code I used last and appended some stuff to it. The last line is rather unreadable though, so after finding something that works you may want to break it into several lines and use some nicely named variables to store the intermediate results.

The ideal way to do it depends on which aspects of the line you can depend on always being like they are here. (E.g. if the #apple part is optional so that it may not be there at all.) You may need to split on different characters or index into the resulting lists from the end of the list using negative indices (e.g. mylist[-1] to get the last item).

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` to test membership:

```
>>> s='#apple (orange3ball/345-35:;bat9cap/253-43) school=(book,pen,bottle)'
>>> 'orange3ball' in s
True
>>> 'orange4ball' in s
False
>>> 'bat9cap' in s
True
>>> 'bat9ball' in s
False
```

You can also use a regex to break apart on word boundaries:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'(?:\W*(\w+))', s)
['apple', 'orange3ball', '345', '35', 'bat9cap', '253', '43', 'school', 'book', 'pen', 'bottle']
```

The advantage of the second method is that only entire matches are a match in the resulting list:

```
>>> 'or' in s
True
>>> 'or' in re.findall(r'(?:\W*(\w+))', s)
False
```

Or just use a single regex to test for the whole word:

```
>>> re.search(r'\borange3ball\b', s)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 19), match='orange3ball'>
>>> re.search(r'\borange\b', s)
>>>
```

(The return of a match object is a positive match...)